# How to indentify the purchased products after checkout?

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe checkout session that triggers a webhook when a transaction is completed. The webhook retrieves a list of line_items that were purchased and is supposed to identify the products in the database so that it can set the status in the database to 'sold'.

```
// api/checkout

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    mode: 'payment',
    line_items: req.body.itemsIDs.map(itemId => {
        const storeItem = items.find(i => i.id === itemId);

        return {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                    name: "My Product",
                    images: [storeItem.preview]
                    // Can I save the itemId here somehow? I need it in the webhook later to identify the product in the db

                },
                unit_amount: storeItem.price * 100
            },
            quantity: 1
        }
    }),
    success_url: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/success`,
    cancel_url: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}`
});
```

In the webhook, I have access to the session's purchased items (line_items), but I have no way of finding this item in the database. Here's what the line_item object looks like:

```
  {
    id: 'li_1M4iB1DjiBaV2GrrFmb0bTVD', // this is NOT the MongoDB Id that I need, it's a Stripe-generated id
    object: 'item',
    amount_discount: 0,
    amount_subtotal: 100,
    amount_tax: 0,
    amount_total: 100,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'My Product',
    price: {
      id: 'price_1M4iB1DjiBaV2Grr6SnKEWdC',
      object: 'price',
      active: false,
      billing_scheme: 'per_unit',
      created: 1668591903,
      currency: 'usd',
      custom_unit_amount: null,
      livemode: false,
      lookup_key: null,
      metadata: {},
      nickname: null,
      product: 'prod_Mo4ql746Hw4pck',
      recurring: null,
      tax_behavior: 'unspecified',
      tiers_mode: null,
      transform_quantity: null,
      type: 'one_time',
      unit_amount: 100,
      unit_amount_decimal: '100'
    },
    quantity: 1
  }
```

Comment: ok. So what happens instead?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood I edited the post to better explain the issue

Comment: when you construct the callback you can also include arbitary data such that you can use it to identify the product on your side. So e.g. the callback URL can be provided such that /product=1234 to allow you to make that change on your side.

Comment: so e.g. success/product_id=1234

Comment: you should of course validate that the callback URL originates from stripe via the shared secret etyc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing `line_items.price_data` [1] to the creation request of the Checkout Session, you are creating a new price on each purchase. You should instead use `line_items.price` [2] with existing Stripe Prices[3] and Product[4]. You can set your own Ids in the Metadata of both prices [5] and products[6].

After completing the Checkout Session and when receiving the Webhook, you’ll get the Prices with its metadata that contains your database related Ids,  as you have access to the session's purchased items (line_items).

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create

[5] https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-metadata

[6] https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create#create_product-metadata

[7] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed